# GTK List with images and Text and other widgets

Tags: c, gtk

I am building a simple chat application under GTK+ and C,
In that i need to display List of contacts like follows.

1.
Window Containing contact list with contacts Presence and status Icons and name.

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| [PresenceImage1] [Name1] [StatusImage1] |
| [PresenceImage2] [Name2] [StatusImage2] |
| [PresenceImage3] [Name3] [StatusImage3] |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

2.
When user clicks on any of the contacts it will expand 
and will display information/options with the list.

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| [PresenceImage1] [Name1] [StatusImage1] |
|  +------------------------------------+ |
|  |[ButtonCall]       [ButtonMoreInfo] | |
|  |[ContactImage]                      | |
|  +------------------------------------+ |
| [PresenceImage2] [Name2] [StatusImage2] |
| [PresenceImage3] [Name3] [StatusImage3] |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Is it possible in GTK?
How to create 1st and 2nd Screens?
Which components to use achieve this functionality?
Can anyone provide code snaps/examples?

Thanks!
Pradeep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GtkExpander](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkExpander.html)